# Longhorn node draining

Tags: kubernetes, longhorn

When draining a node after having cordoned it as stated in the [documentation](https://longhorn.io/docs/1.6.0/maintenance/maintenance/#updating-the-node-os-or-container-runtime) we get the following error:
`error when evicting pods/"instance-manager-xxx" -n "longhorn-system" (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.`

Having the allowed disruptions of the instance manager pods set to 0 seems to cause the issue:
[image]

How is it possible to drain a node containing Longhorn on it? Is there a value related to the pod disruption budget we can update in the Helm chart? We need this for in-place Kubernetes upgrades.

This anwser is close to what we need, but involves manual steps that are not possible in an Ansible automated way of upgrading Kubernetes: https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn/discussions/4102#discussioncomment-3118777

We use Longhorn version 1.5.3 installed using helm chart.